# iOS Safari not respecting z-index

Tags: ios, css, safari

I don't even know how to explain this in words, so here's an image with annotations:

[image]

On the left is iOS Simulator, on the right is Safari. There's a Material UI AppBar that has a lower z-index. This is the structure:

[image]

I'm completely stumped. In every browser, this works fine.

Codepen here, that is the same issue: http://codepen.io/ffxsam/pen/NxwZQv

Not posting the whole code here, as there's a ton of lorem ipsum. But StackOverflow requires something, so here's the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app-bar {
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 64px;
  background: #999;
  position: relative;
}

.big {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.viewport {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  top: 64px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  z-index: 9000;
}
```

It seems like if the overlay div is a child of the content you want to overlay, all the z-index in the world won't make it work. It has to be outside everything else in the DOM hierarchy. Though in React, that can be tricky because you want the overlay to access certain props, and moving it out of the container has implications as far as data transfer.

Comment: There are some problems with position fixed on mobile, so you are best to steer clear of using it.

Comment: Even if I switch everything that's `fixed` to `absolute`, the problem still persists.

Comment: http://codepen.io/pen/ perhaps?

Comment: @ffxsam the fiddle link is dead. Also this sounds like a problem of z-index stacking context. It might be worth reading some in depth information on z-index behaviour since it does not quite work as you might expect. In your case it sound as if a parent/sibling element somewhere has a higher z-index, causing the child index to have no effect (not exactly true but comment character limit blocks me from explaining it in detail). Interesting read: [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I

1. swapped the order of the `<div class="overlay">` and `<div class="viewport">` in the html
2. Altered the css of `.overlay`

html

```
<div>
  <div class="app-bar">
    <span class="big">Hello.</span>
    <button class="open-overlay">
      Open Overlay
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay">
      <button class="close-overlay">
        Close this.
      </button>
      <p>00000</p>
      <p>11111</p>
      <p>22222</p>
      <p>33333</p>
      <p>44444</p>
      <p>55555</p>
      <button class="close-overlay">
        Close this.
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="viewport">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est corporis cum iure id voluptatibus inventore recusandae veniam dolorum harum, minus officia blanditiis asperiores illum laudantium tenetur doloremque hic ea atque!
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis illo eligendi magnam laudantium tenetur in consequatur aperiam totam beatae, accusamus sed, distinctio cum quam. Unde dolores ut consectetur temporibus similique.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est corporis cum iure id voluptatibus inventore recusandae veniam dolorum harum, minus officia blanditiis asperiores illum laudantium tenetur doloremque hic ea atque!
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis illo eligendi magnam laudantium tenetur in consequatur aperiam totam beatae, accusamus sed, distinctio cum quam. Unde dolores ut consectetur temporibus similique.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est corporis cum iure id voluptatibus inventore recusandae veniam dolorum harum, minus officia blanditiis asperiores illum laudantium tenetur doloremque hic ea atque!
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis illo eligendi magnam laudantium tenetur in consequatur aperiam totam beatae, accusamus sed, distinctio cum quam. Unde dolores ut consectetur temporibus similique.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app-bar {
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 64px;
  background: #999;
  position: relative;
}

.big {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.viewport {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  top: 64px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.overlay {
  position:relative;
  display: none;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:calc(100vh - 64px); /* viewport height minus .app-bar height */
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  z-index: 9000;
}
```

js

```
$('.open-overlay').on('click', function () {
  $('.overlay').fadeIn();
});

$('.close-overlay').on('click', function() {
  $('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjJZKB